# Anchor point positionings

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a long vertical website created using a Wordpress vertical scrolling '*parallax*' type theme. All the content areas are created via 'posts' - with the post titles being the H1s.

I've created a sticky menu at the top of the page calling anchor points I've set within the post titles in attempt to have the most accuracy with positioning. *Eg below.*

```
<a name="ebook"></a>Ebook
```

This didn't work as now it scrolled to the point displaying only half of the content as my sticky menu is covering the title area where I set the anchor. So it scrolls down with the menu covering half of the content.

So, I thought what if I assigned a class to my anchors and margined it up about 200px to have the anchor scroll to the content just right. This didn't work either. *Eg below*

```
 <a name="ebook" class="anchor"></a>Ebook
```

**Could anyone guide me with a solution to this? I need to position my anchors about 200px above my Wordpress posts / content areas, for the content to appear nicely.**

*(I'm already using `smoothscroll.js` to create a smooth transitions between the anchors, and would rather not look at implementing an additional or different JS / I'm looking for a CSS solution. )*

Comment: What is in the `smoothscroll.js` script?  You may be able to just edit that script to allow for the additional space on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little unclear (an example would have been nice), but if I understand you correctly I think I've had a similar issue myself in the past. An `<a>` will always jump to the top of the page, so if you have a sticky nav, it is going to cover the `<a>` info (which I think is part of what you were saying in the first instance). I'm not sure why you feel you need 200px (that is unclear).

However, here is what I would do: **set a `block` or `inline-block` display and a `padding-top` on your `<a>` tag's that is at least equal to the height of your sticky nav.** What this will do is put the top of the `a` still at the top of the page, but allow the text to get bumped down. You can then position your content whatever distance you want from the bottom of the `a`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6zAYw/6/

Comment: Thanks - but hadn't worked. I think I've described it better here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380034/setting-custom-anchorpoint