# Setting Custom Anchorpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to set anchor points customley, in positions outside of where the actual HTML mark up is?

I'm using this simple parallax scrolling script called '`smoothscroll.js`' at '*http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/smoothscroll/smoothscroll.js*'

It works by making links to anchor points. *HOWEVER*, I need to position them outside of where the markup lays. **About 200px above.**

I've tried external CSS with a class and inline.

***EG:***

```
<a name="kids" class="anchor" style="margin-top:-200px;"></a>


<a name="kids" class="anchor" style="margin-top:-200px;"></a>

.anchor { margin-top: -200px; }
```

Any suggestions?!

This question is a derivation of this one, [Anchor point positionings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335942/anchor-point-positionings) (2 - Q points, for the help!)

Comment: Are you using any `position` in the CSS?

Comment: As in 'position: absolute;'? No, should I?

Comment: Yes, as it will dictate what the -200px is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `a` is not a block element, `margin-top` will not work as expected.

Here's some modified CSS:

```
.anchor {
  display: block;
  position: relative; /* relative to the parent container, needed for top/left positioning*/
  top: -200px;
}
```

Comment: I used position: absolute; and set a margin via inline style. But thanks!