# Setting custom anchor point inside of HTML

Tags: html, css

I have seen this topic somewhat covered in posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380034/setting-custom-anchorpoint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335942/anchor-point-positionings), but they don't really help me out.  The situation is fairly similar though: a scrolling page and a sticky menu bar (fixed div) at the top of the page, with anchor points scattered through the long scrolling text.

Something like this HTML:

```
<a name="hd1" class="anchor"><h1>Heading Foo</h1></a>
<p>this is some text, and a lot of it
...
<a href="#hd1">jump to Heading Foo</a>
...
<a name="hdx" class="anchor"><h1>Heading Bla</h1></a>
<p>and then there is more text
...
<a href="#hdx">jump to Heading Bla</a>    
...
```

with some CSS that, for now, is empty because I still just stumble around this issue

```
.anchor {
  color: green;
} ​
```

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QCv27/) fiddle to see how it works at the moment.

Now, whenever I click on a link it takes me to the anchor.  (Yay!)  Alas, this also means that the anchor, now at the top of the page, is covered by the sticky menu.  (Nay!)  It would be great if it would show *below* the sticky menu.

I've tried the solutions that were given in the other posts to no avail.  For example, adding padding around the anchor does actually add visible padding in the text and create empty space; which is not what I want.  The text ought to appear unmodified visually.

Thanks in advance for hints and tips :-)

EDIT: I should make it a little more clear.  I do *not* need space on top of the page.  I do need *every* anchor point to be *below* the menu bar.  Try my original fiddle, and click the anchors: you will see how they are positioned so that they are covered by the menu bar.

Comment: Warning: the `name` tag is *not* supported in HTML5. Use the global id attribute instead.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input, and I found a working solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996330/changing-default-starting-position-of-anchor) discussion.  The hint from there was "empty anchors"; on my original fiddle the anchors enclosed the heading and that prevented me from positioning the anchors.

Changing to empty anchors

```
<a name="hdx" class="anchor">&nbsp;</a><h1>Heading Bla</h1>
```

allows me to move the anchors on the page without affecting any of the (visible) text flow.  So the CSS for the anchors now becomes

```
.anchor {
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;  /* depending on the size of the sticky menu */
}
```

That way, the anchor for a heading is positioned *above* the heading, and jumping to that anchor causes the heading to show up *below* the menu bar.

I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCv27/20/) to work correctly.  (Two things: the anchors use A1, .. text to show their position but you can empty them.  Also, I had to explicitly close the `<p>` tags to ensure "position:relative" works ok.)

Comment: Just one note: an empty anchor doesn't quite work, use `<a ..>&nbsp</a>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What about to set padding for the first h1 ?

```
​h1:first-child {
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Try it, that won't work because the padding gets scrolled along with the rest ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a container div to hold rest of the data and set padding-top:50px;

CSS:
    #contents{
    padding-top:50px;/* height of menu */
    }

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
<div id="contents">
<!-- data goes here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using Javascript and `window.scrollTo` to scroll the page to where you want to go? You can find the `offsetTop` of the element, and then scroll to the current `scrollX` and the offsetTop + however tall your header is?

Comment: Is there a CSS/HTML only solution to this?  But let me try this one, it makes sense.

Comment: I noodled around with this but it got a bit messy.  Installed an onclick handler which then iterated over all anchors of the "anchor" class to pick the target one.  So far, so good.  Then I had problems finding that anchor's position and it all started to go off the tangent.  Found a CSS solution that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add aditional one class and set that margin-top value

Html

```
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
 <div class="nontop">
  //-- some thing here
</div>
```

Css

```
.nontop {
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

here the Deml: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCv27/17/)

Comment: This is similar to the first answer by Varon: padding/marging gets scrolled too.  In my fiddle, click on any of the links and you'll see how the page jumps _under_ the menu.  Even with your edit.

Answer (score 0):

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bindashsandeep/mLCE3/1/)
Want to do like this.

Create a div with `margin-top:50px;` & keep all are in container div, except the menu div.

Comment: Same as answer by Selva and Davon: doesn't work.  Click on any of the anchors and text still jumps _under_ the menu bar.

Comment: Click on the Live Demo link you provided.  Then click on "Jump to a1".  The text is now covered by the menu bar, and that is not what I asked.  What I want is the text _not_ be covered by the menu bar and right below it.