# Website anchors are moving when font size changes

Tags: html, css, anchor

This question is a follow-up of [a previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304326/setting-custom-anchor-point-inside-of-html) one.  In brief, I have a website that looks roughly like this:

```
<head>
  <style>
    a.anchor {
      position: relative;
      top: -2em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="position:fixed; left:0, top:0; width:100%; height:2em"> ... </div>

  <a name="anchor1" class="anchor">&nbsp</a>
  <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
  ...

  <a name="anchor2" class="anchor">&nbsp</a>
  <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
  ...

</body>
```

and I can target the individual headlines by `index.html#anchor1` and so forth.  Anchors are placed relative at `-2em` because that's the size of the top `<div>` and so the headlines align nicely just below.  This all works fine.

However, when I change the font size of the website then its entire content shifts (of course) and the headline that used to sit nicely aligned right under the top `<div>` moves around.  Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mc93W/) although it doesn't seem to reproduce the issue too well.

Question: is there a way to keep the headline aligned while changing the fontsize?  The only thing I can think of would be a Javascript reload using the URL with anchor.  Something more elegant, perhaps?

Comment: jsfiddle or it didn't happen ;)

Comment: name has become deprecated - you should use an id

Comment: Are you using any css resets? I find ems a bit unpredictable without a 0 based reset.

Comment: Isn't the em measurement based on the font size? so when the font size changes, 2em changes.

Comment: @Horen: Added.  @Pete: Thanks.  @Daniel: Yes.  @Chad: That's not the point.  The point is that with font-size changes the anchors move around, but I would like a headline to stay where it's at—aligned right under the `<div>`.  If the `2em` is too confusing, substitute it with `20px` and you'll still have the same happening.